# Laravel methods on how it stores and flash/remove when session expires in database?

Tags: php, laravel

Good day everyone! Got some question regarding with Laravel Sessions.

- Every time the page is accessed with a different browser, laravel put a session on the table session and i've been wondering how does laravel do this?
- What class and methods does laravel use to handle this?
- Can this method be overrided?
- If this method can be overrided, can i add an attribute to be stored also in the session table?

Thank you so much for your answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Larvel sourcecode in front of me, but I'd guess the [StartSession middleware](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.html) takes care of this. You could extend this middleware and add some data to it I guess, although it would be cleaner to create your own middleware similar to how the StartSession one is setup and add the data you want in there.

Comment: Find another way around to do what i wanted though, thank you for the help.